# SELECT statement not returing the Result

Tags: sql, sql-server

My Select statement looks like

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE name = 'Test Test'
```

Where the name field is a `varchar` field and value 'Test Test' have no spaces before or after

But if I change it to

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE name LIKE 'Test Test%'
```

Then it works

any idea?

Comment: could you include some sample data and the ouput you are getting with each of this statement?

Comment: if 'Test Test%' happens to work then there most be something written right after it. Try logging the table output and check for hidden characters or whitespaces

Comment: What is the output of `SELECT len(name) FROM Customers WHERE name LIKE 'Test Test%'` ? Is it coming more than 9? If yes then there definitely exist some whitespace or hidden character.

Comment: Function Len doesn't count trailing spaces.

Comment: Try SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE name LIKE '%Test Test' , see if this also  works or not because there are chance of having some blank space characters after your actual value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check existence of trailing spaces with next query

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE LEN(REPLACE(name, ' ', '?')) - LEN(name) > 0
```

If it will return rows in case when name has trailing spaces.